# Getting history from CVS archive

Tags: cvs, history, extract

I'm trying to automatically extract data from our cvs archive.

When I do a log on our current revision, I can get all changes to the revision I am interested in for a single file:

```
cvs log -rcurrent-release foo.cc
```

but then I have to interate through all the files, and some no longer exist since they were deleted.

Is there a way to iterate through all the history entries in the order in which they occurred?

When I try:

```
cvs history
```

I get only my own history, in sequential order.

I can specify by user:

```
cvs history -u foo
```

But what I'd like is everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to look into [cvs2cl](http://www.red-bean.com/cvs2cl/), you'll be able to generate delta between two tags.

Comment: I can't get it to output lines changed, so I'm looking for an easier answer, but in the meantime trying to hack the code to do what I want, it's mostly there...

Comment: I think it will do it but only in xml

Answer (score 0):

To get the history of all changes of files for all users, use this command:

> cvs history -a -c module/

One problem with this though is that the output is not sorted chronologically. The output also displays changes in all branches.

If you want to have the output sorted chronologically and only for a particular branch, there is a script to do that:
https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/display-the-history-of-cvs-commits-similar-to-git-or-svn/